# The following statement returns an “ambiguous identifier” error. Re-write the SQL statement to get rid of the error:

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, ambiguous

Can you please help me solve the error

```
SELECT user_id, firstname, id, office_name, lastname, email, office_name
    
    FROM users u JOIN offices o on o.id = u.office_id
```

Comment: tl;dr where a column exists in more than one table you need to alias it. For example, if `id` exists in both `users` and `offices` then Oracle doesn't know whether you want to use `users.id` or `offices.id` so you need to choose, e.g. `o.id`.

Comment: I would go even further, and alias all the columns for queries that include multiple columns.